# UI Bootstrap radio button in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to do a set of radio buttons using ui bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) pretty much the same that the example on their website, but using ng-repeat:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label ng-repeat='option in options' class="btn btn-danger" ng-model="radioModel2" btn-radio="'{{option}}'" uncheckable>{{option}}</label>
</div>
```

but for some reason it doesn't work when I use ng-repeat. Anyone knows why?

I've made a plunker to illustrate the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/0sDgKoRhHOgfnIvBPmi4?p=preview

Thanks!

Comment: checkout [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/KYXcwkMmN592wBq2PAnI?p=preview). ng-repeat creates is new scope. So you need to create an object at parent controller to share result.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are doing a little mistake with your ng-model.
When you are going to pass it in radiobutton with repeat in you model you can use it like

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label ng-repeat='option in options' class="btn btn-danger" ng-model="$parent.radioModel2" btn-radio="'{{option}}'" uncheckable>{{option}}</label>
</div>
```

Try this.

Check the link on plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/m24ZcYuttw6IuCBh02rQ?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

From the [Understanding Scopes angular.js wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-repeat):

> For each item/iteration, ng-repeat creates a new scope, which
> prototypically inherits from the parent scope, **but it also assigns the
> item's value to a new property on the new child scope.**
>
> If item is a primitive *(boolean, string, int, etc.),* essentially a copy
> of the value is assigned to the new child scope property. Changing the
> child scope property's value does not change the array the parent scope references.

With *italic* are my comments.

However, things work differently when you have an object provided, because in this case only a reference to the original object is assigned to the child scope and not a copy.

Thus, you can make your example work by substituting your `ng-model="radioModel2"` with `ng-model="data.radioModel2"` and in your controller don't forget to create the object with `$scope.data = {};`

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/R1Ny2E7KGAkJX4OOR8wv?p=preview) is a working fork of your plunker.